# Is it possible to use StringFormat or Constant Variable in android Room Query

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to query the user associations list with the following room query using public constant variable **Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED**.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = " + Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED)
LiveData<List<Association>> loadUserAssociations();
```

But, room gives me [SQLITE_ERROR] when build.
 It is possible to re-write that query by replacing the constant variable with parameter like the following.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = :statusApproved")
LiveData<List<Association>> loadUserAssociations(String statusApproved);
```

I would like to know that does Room support such kind of string concatenation or String Format? (or) May be I missing something?

Comment: the 2nd one should work.. is there any error?

Comment: Yes, @DKV. The 2nd one works. But, I prefer the 1st one and I just want to know does Room support such kind of string concatenation or string format.

Comment: No, it's not possible with first type.

Comment: Thanks @JeelVankhede. I think Room should support like that :-D How do you think? :-)

Comment: No, actually it's not fault of **ROOM**, but you can't pass variables to `Annotations` it must be static final value.

Answer (score 7):

For those who have the same problem, the following could be the solution in Kotlin:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = :statusApproved")
loadUserAssociations(statusApproved: String = Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED): LiveData<List<Association>>
```

And I think it is more clean way than hardcoding or passing obvious constant into the function.

Comment: Can we use enums in the query like the following   "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE status =   STATES.RUNNING.ordinal()"

Comment: Not sure but I'd expect you need a converter for the Enums. So your converter might look like this:

[at]TypeConverter
fun toEnum(value: MyEnum?) = value?.let { enumValueOf<MyEnum>(it) }

[at]TypeConverter
fun fromEnum(value: MyEnum?) = value?.name

not sure it works but give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

you can query like below.

Instead of

`@Query("SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = " + Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED) LiveData<List<Association>> loadUserAssociations();`

use

`@Query("SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus=${Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED}) LiveData<List<Association>> loadUserAssociations();`

Comment: Do you have a link to the reference docs for this? I can't get "expression expected" compile time error on the $ sign

Answer (score 0):

- problem

if you make a query like this,

> "SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = " + Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED

it's just

> "SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = somevalue"

sql cannot know "somvalue" is a string.

---

- try this (wrap it with quotation mark)

> "SELECT * FROM Association WHERE memberStatus = '" + Association.MEMBER_STATUS_APPROVED + "'"

Comment: Can we use enums in the query like the following   "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE status =    STATES.RUNNING.ordinal()"